# Transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning, linear-transformations, transformation

> For $x \in \mathbb{C}$ define $A,B \in M(3\times3, \mathbb{C})$ as $$ A = \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & x & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & x \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$ B = \begin{pmatrix} x & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & x & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & x \end{pmatrix}. $$ Now I want to find a transformation matrix $T \in \text{GL}_3(\mathbb{C})$ with 
>   $B = T^{-1}AT$.

---

I am able to perform row/column manipulations to get from A to B, but I yield a wrong result when trying to combine those manipulations via elementary matrices. What is the right way to come up with the matrix T?

Comment: Be careful that you need to multiply the elementary matrix on the correct side of $A$ or $B$. How did you get the wrong result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product from the right = operation on columns, product from the left = operation on rows, so take

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}\implies T^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\;\;,\;\;\;\text{and}$$

$$T^{-1}AT=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x&0&0\\0&x&1\\0&0&x\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}=$$$${}$$

$$=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0&x\\x&1&0\\0&x&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x&1&0\\0&x&0\\0&0&x\end{pmatrix}=B$$

Comment: Thanks, Joanpemo! I know how to invert matrices and also the transformation itself but could you expand just a little bit on how you came up with $T = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$? I get that from the right are operations on columns and from the left operations on rows but how did you come up with T in this very example?

Comment: Good answer! just to add to it, what @Joanpemo did is observe that $B$ can be obtained from $A$ by performing a sequence of row "swaps" and an equivalent set of column swaps. In particular, $T^{-1}$ reorders the rows of $A$ (because it's multiplying on the left) as follows: row #2, row #3, row #1. $T$ will reorder the columns of $A$ (because it's multiplying on the right) as follows: column #2, column #3, column #1.

Comment: @Taufi Karla's excellent comment explained it. Observe that, for example,  rows 1-2 swapped = columns 1-2 swapped...and that's the secret.

Comment: So there was a trick after all! Thanks, Karla H. and Joanpemo!